# How to insert date inside json in html element

Tags: javascript, json, html

I have json inside meta tag attribute:

```
<head>
  <title>PLD Interaction pattern</title>
    <meta data-pageObject='{
      "page": {
        "pageInfo":   {
          "pageID": "12345",
          "pageName": "smartphones:samsung-galaxy-s-5",
          "prevPageName": "phones",
          "version": "1.15",
          "language": "en-US",
          "geoRegion": "US",
          "responsiveState": "desktop",
          "timeStamp": "+new Date()+", //Insert date here
          "currencyCode": "USD"
        }
      }
    }' id="metaJson">
</head>
```

I need to insert date into `timestamp` key. I tried to escape using `'` but its showing syntax error. Is there a way to escape it and insert date?

Comment: This is just an HTML snippet, not a JS code

Comment: @AlonEitan is `new Date()` not JS inside HTML?

Comment: You can't add a `date` object to JSON like that. It has to be string representation like `2016-03-28` which you can get a date object from when you process the JSON later. To add the string, take the JSON, parse it, add the string at in the right place, stringify it again and place it back in that element.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. You need to create thg and apply the attribute to it, then add it into the document (Using JS code). Or if you use some server side with it, print the data into the document on the server (`<?php echo '"timeStamp": ' . time() . ', //Insert date here'; ?>` - PHP example)

Comment: "timeStamp": "+new Date()+", is a string , not a date object

Comment: Fair point. `+newDate()+` actually gives an error tho. `+new Date()` works.

Comment: @Andy I already tried `+new Date()` it didn't work for me

Comment: @Andy could you paste a working sample if its working for you

Comment: I don't have it working. I merely wrote down the steps you should take to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use JavaScript to get the string, convert from JSON to an object, add the date and later stringify the object into the data-attribute again. You can't execute JavaScript in a data-attribute, data-attributes only stores arbitrary data.

Don't confuse JSON with JavaScript. JSON is language independent and represents objects, is not a programming language.

Run the code and inspect the iframe to check the added date.

```js
var metaJson = document.getElementsByTagName('meta').item(property='metaJson');
var data = metaJson.getAttribute('data-pageObject');
data = JSON.parse(data);
data.date = new Date();
metaJson.setAttribute('data-pageObject', JSON.stringify(data));
```

```html
    <meta name="metaJson" data-pageObject='{
      "page": {
        "pageInfo":   {
          "pageID": "12345",
          "pageName": "smartphones:samsung-galaxy-s-5",
          "prevPageName": "phones",
          "version": "1.15",
          "language": "en-US",
          "geoRegion": "US",
          "responsiveState": "desktop",
          "currencyCode": "USD"
        }
      }
    }' id="metaJson">
```